# send command to linux tmux through ssh from OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I am using tmux on a linux machine. I ssh into the linux machine from a mac osx machine but the tmux commands are being applied to my mac terminal instead of the tmux on linux. For example, control+b+d would close the tmux window on linux but instead it is intercepted by my mac terminal and creates a split panel instead. How do I send the command through to tmux?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: just the default osx one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit confusing. Are you running tmux on your OS X machine as well, so there are two tmux? If so, you need to press `C-b C-b` (two `C-b` to send the prefix through to the inside tmux).

If not, it sounds like your terminal uses `C-b` for something else, you can either change the prefix in tmux to something your terminal doesn't use (see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#changing-the-prefix-key), or configure your terminal not to use `C-b`.

Comment: I see. No, I am not running tmux on OSX but c-b is used for something else in osx terminal...